# How to add public bitbucket repo in package.json or bower.json

Tags: npm, bitbucket, bower, node-modules, package.json

I have a library pushed on bitbucket as public repo. I want its link to used in package.json dependencies object. I have tried various https formats but not one is working.

```
"library_name": "https://username@bitbucket.org/repo_name.git"

"library_name": bitbucket://bitbucket.com/username/repo_name.git

"library_name": "bitbucket@bitbucket.com:username/repo_name.git#master
```

Or I can add it in bower.json? I don't want to use it directly like npm install repo_url

The error I get is something like

```
ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://username@bitbucket.org/dv.keystone.git", exit code of #128 remote: Not Found fatal: unable to access 'https://username@bitbucket.org/reponame.git/': GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

remote: Not Found
fatal: unable to access 'https://username@bitbucket.org/repo_name.git/': GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

**Update:**

```
"lib_name": "https://username@bitbucket.org/team_name/repo_name.git"
```

It works in bower.json but I need this in package.json to work. If I use it in package.json, it gives this error

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/npm-16628-b0121d64/git-cache-cbc9eb1e/7c4c6a5fb3e77723f3866c99fdf0825ba7cc0c5c
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-39-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
```

Comment: Just to clarify - where you have ```username@bitbucket.org``` are you using ```username``` as a placeholder fo this question, or is this what you are actually adding to your JSON files?

Comment: this is a placeholder just for this question.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to add BitBucket modules in `package.json`. The way I do add github repo as,

`"library-name": "git+https://github.com/user/library-name.git"`

So to think about just replacing the github part it should be

`"library-name": "git+https://bitbucket.org/user/library-name.git"`

Comment: Bitbucket and Github have different URL structures. Don't think your example would work.

Comment: Ah sorry then, I could help if you can provide me the repo you want to add. I can try on my pc and update you.

Answer (score 2):

Did some googling for you - as I wasn't sure myself.

This may work for you:

`git+https://bitbucket.org/{user}/{repo}.git`

Comment: Seems like same as my answer, though I missed the `.org` part earlier.

Comment: @SajjadHossain well spotted. Didn't initially notice.